# How use my own scss variable file in Quasar template

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite, quasar

I want to use my own SCSS fil with variable that I already set with Quasar.
for example in Q-tab

```
<q-tabs
        v-model="selectedTab"
        align="left"
        indicator-color="transparent"
        active-color="$MyOwnVariable"
>
```

My project is a Vue3 with vite js

I tried to create a quasar.variables.scss in css folder but it doesn't work

Comment: How doesn't it work? Did you get an error message? Did it just not show up? Where did you get the code from?

Answer (score 0):

Here is I think how it should be set

**quasar.config.js**

```
css: [
  'app.scss'
]
```

**quasar.variables.scss**

```
$brand-primary: #EAC30D;
```

**app.scss**

```
.brand-primary {
  background-color: $brand-primary;
}
```

**YourComponent.vue**

```
<q-btn class="brand-primary" label="Caption" />
```